Nuxt sitemap adding the default lastmod for the dynamic routes during the sitemap.xml generation
I am generating the sitemap.xml for my Nuxt 3 based Nuxt Content website pages and everything works fine and able to get the correct sitemap after running the npm run generate or nuxt generate. However I am unable to add the default value for lastmod for dynamically created routes. I have created a sample re-production in CodeSandBox.
My /content/imprint/index.md file looks like this:
---
title: "Imprint"
description: "Imprint/Registration information"
navigation:
    linkTitle: "Imprint"
    tags : ["convert", "compliance", "json"]
head:
  meta:
    - name: 'keywords'
sitemap:
  loc: /imprint
  lastmod: 2024-08-31
  changefreq: monthly
  priority: 1
---

And I get the following information within my sitemap.xml like this:
<url>
    <loc>https://localhost:3003/imprint</loc>
    <lastmod>2024-08-31</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>1</priority>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://localhost:3003/imprint" hreflang="x-default" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://localhost:3003/imprint" hreflang="en" />
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://localhost:3003/tags/convert</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://localhost:3003/tags/convert" hreflang="x-default" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://localhost:3003/tags/convert" hreflang="en" />
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://localhost:3003/tags/compliance</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://localhost:3003/tags/compliance" hreflang="x-default" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://localhost:3003/tags/compliance" hreflang="en" />
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://localhost:3003/tags/json</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://localhost:3003/tags/json" hreflang="x-default" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://localhost:3003/tags/json" hreflang="en" />
</url>

As we can see since I defined the lastmod for my imprint/index.md page I got the lastmod for only for that URL but for all the tags or dynamic routes which get created in the sitemap.xml it does not get the lastmod or changeFreq added by default to it.
I want to know how can I add the default lastmod value to all the dynamic tags routes during the generation of the sitemap.xml? If present from the file then add it directly if not then add the lastest or current date time lastmod: new Date(),
I tried to add the defaults to my nuxt.config.js:
  sitemap: {
    hostname: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL,
    gzip: true,
    trailingSlash: true,
    defaults: {
      changefreq: "daily",
      priority: 1,
      lastmod: new Date(),
    },
  },

But this did not make any difference and I did not get the lastmod for the /tags. How to ensure if the lastmod to be added for all the URLS generated in sitemap.xml including the dynamic routes?
I tried couple of things already:
  sitemap: {
    hostname: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL,
    trailingSlash: true,
    lastmod: new Date(),
    defaults: {
      lastmod: new Date()
    }
  },

Also added custom routes logic:
 sitemap: {
    filter ({ routes }) {
      return routes.map(route => {
        route.url = `${route.url}/`
        route.lastmod = new Date()
        return route
      })
    }
  }

I have created a sample re-production in CodeSandBox.
Following is my nuxt.config.js:

Click to toggle contents of `nuxt.config.js`
export default {
  compatibilityDate: "2024-08-31",

  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
    "unplugin-fonts/nuxt",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n",
    "@nuxtjs/color-mode",
    "@nuxt/image",
    "@nuxt/content",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap",
  ],

  ssr: true,
  target: 'static',

  site: {
    url: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/',
    name: "Test Application",
    trailingSlash: true,
    defaults: {
      changefreq: "daily",
      priority: 1,
      lastmod: new Date(),
    },
  },

  //To support and display the .md files from /content using @nuxt/content
  content: {
    // To highlight the code sections using the theme
    highlight: {
      theme: {
        default: "aurora-x",
        dark: "everforest-dark",
        sepia: "monokai",
      },
      langs: ["json", "xml", "java", "shell"],
    },
    
    markdown: {
      remarkPlugins: ["remark-reading-time"], //To get the reading time for each .md file in /content
      anchorLinks: false, // Do not underline and highlight the h2, h3, h4 etc
    }
  },

  //To support the dark/light mode theme using @nuxtjs/color-mode
  colorMode: {
    classSuffix: "",
    preference: "system",
    fallback: "dark",
  },

  app: {
    head: {
      link: [
        {
          rel: "icon",
          type: "image/x-icon",
          href: `/img/favicon.ico`,
        },
      ],
    },
  },

  buildModules: [
    {
      vue: {
        config: {
          assetDirs: ["assets", "public"],
        },
      },
    },
  ],

  runtimeConfig: {
    apiSecret: "123",
    public: {},
  },

  components: [
    {
      path: "~/components",
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
  ],

  build: {
    postcss: {
      postcssOptions: {
        plugins: {
          tailwindcss: {},
          autoprefixer: {},
        },
      },
    },
  },

  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: "en",
        files: ["en.json", "en-extended.json"],
      },
    ],
    lazy: true,
    langDir: "./locales",
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },

  plugins: [{ src: "@/plugins/aos", ssr: false, mode: "client" }],
};


Did you find a solution for this? I currently have the same question

@AChichi No i did not try but this is the response i got: https://github.com/nuxt-modules/sitemap/issues/366

@AChichi https://github.com/nuxt-modules/sitemap/issues/366#issuecomment-2415921355

Did you try autoLastmod: true it worked for my needs

@AChichi Yup I did try in site of nuxt.config but it was not adding the current date for the routes. I was getting the dates only for the content .md files for which I have already provided lastmod: 2024-08-31. May be if you have an example nuxt.config file you can provide here i can compare and see what am I missing.

I don't think we have the same needs, but you can find my config here : https://github.com/nuxt-modules/sitemap/issues/372#issuecomment-2413591698


If present from the file then add it directly if not then add the lastest or current date time lastmod: new Date()

I would recommend against setting lastmod to any kind of default value. If you are unable to accurately determine the last modification date of a page, simply do not insert the <lastmod> tag in the XML sitemap, i.e. don't do anything :)
This can be inferred from Google's XML sitemap documentation (emphasis mine):

The <lastmod> value should reflect the date and time of the last significant update to the page. For example, an update to the main content, the structured data, or links on the page is generally considered significant, however an update to the copyright date is not.

But it is further clarified and expanded on in the Search Engine Journal article "Google’s Gary Illyes: Lastmod Signal Is Binary" (emphasis mine):

Google either accepts the lastmod dates provided in a site’s sitemap as accurate, or it disregards them.
This binary approach reinforces the need to implement the lastmod tag correctly and only specify dates when making meaningful changes.

Finally, if you insist on having a lastmod value for your Tag pages, I would suggest using the publication date of the most recent article listed in each Tag page, because (in a generic blog logic) Tag pages are auto-updated every time an article is added to the Tag. However, this will require more work with little to no gain in terms of SEO.
Hope this helps!
